# How can I change the login screen?

Tags: 12.04, login-screen

My login screen has changed automatically. I want to change it wants. Where can I do it them?

[image]

Comment: Per user125929: Can you please be more specific? How did it change? I assume you are using 12.04, since it is in the tag. How do you want to change it also.

Comment: Even after your edits and picture: please be more specific. The login screen you're using appears to be KDM (the KDE login screen). Is that what you want to get rid of or customize? Are you running KDE? etc. And I'm lost at the phrases: *"I want to change it wants. Where can I do it them?"* I don't understand this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you installed `kubuntu-desktop` or a similar package.  In a terminal run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm
```

You will get a prompt that looks like this:

[image]

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the prompt, then select `lightdm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this article on [How to change Ubuntu login screen](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45315/how-to-change-the-ubuntu-linux-login-screen/).